# Is resuming from hibernation I/O bound or CPU bound?

Tags: performance, suspend, hibernate

I use hibernation (with encryption) on my laptop, which has 16 GB of RAM, and a fast CPU (Ryzen 6700U).

When resuming, the system takes a while to load the image (13/14 seconds).

Is resuming from (encrypted) hibernation an I/O or CPU bound procedure? I guess it's I/O bound (loading 16 GB from this does take a while, and I guess loading is just a matter of copying the pages to memory), however, I can't test it in any way.

Comment: It's 99% IO bound because this Ryzen CPU features HW AES encoding/decoding at the tune of several gigabytes per second. 14 seconds don't sound like too much anyways.

Comment: Please do specify your OS. If its linux, (hibernation+encryption), do you mean you are running with this patch ? https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220823152108.v2.7.Ibd067e73916b9fae268a5824c2dd037416426af8@changeid/T/

Comment: Additionally in case your system resumed after hibernation and then re-hibernates once again, does resuming from that second hibernation take (much) more time ? (How much ?)

Comment: My educated guess is IO. I've replaced my old hdd with a sdd and resuming hibernation  became real fast.

Comment: And BTW… you get a very simple way to tell by yourself : Use your firmware to significantly underclock your cpu and retest.

Comment: @MC68020 that's a nice idea, but the laptop's firmware is extremely limited :(

Comment: Regarding the O/S, it's a standard Ubuntu 22.04, which nowadays does support hibernation with encryption (although it does it sloppily, as it creates an insufficiently large swap partition).